# wikidata sparql query timeout optimisation

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to retrieve all instances of musicians (Q639669) in a given city (P131) born after 1900. When I pass in the wikidata example city Rotterdam (Q34370) it works. However, replacing the city with a larger city (e.g., Paris, Q90) it will timeout.

Is there a way to optimise this or split into chunks to make repeated queries?

I'm actually only interested the number of cases it returns (i.e. a single value), without needing all the metadata about the artist name, etc.

Would be really helpful if someone can give me pointers to solving this. Thanks!

```
SELECT ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?birth
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P106/wdt:P279* wd:Q639669 .
  ?item wdt:P19/wdt:P131* wd:Q34370 .
  
  OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P569 ?birth}
  
  filter (?birth > "1900-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*` (ZeroOrMore) property path operator used on the P131 ("located in the administrative territorial entity") is one of the culprits here. A simple approach to getting an answer would be to manually run queries that build up that property path one element at a time:

In query 1: `?item wdt:P19 wd:Q34370 .`

In query 2: `?item wdt:P19/wdt:P131 wd:Q34370 .`

In query 3: `?item wdt:P19/wdt:P131/wdt:P131 wd:Q34370 .`

etc.

I found through experimentation that there is no data past 3 occurrences of P131. However, be aware that there are duplicates across these queries, because some people are listed as having birth places both "in Paris" and also in some sub-region of Paris (for example, Claude Arrieu (Q272886) listed as being born in both Paris and the 8th arrondissement).

You can also use `UNION` to put several of these property paths together into a single query, though be aware that this may increase the query time and move you back towards a timeout depending on the data:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?birth WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P106 / wdt:P279 * wd:Q639669 .
    {
        ?item wdt:P19 wd:Q90 .
    } UNION {
        ?item wdt:P19 / wdt:P131 wd:Q90 .
    } UNION {
        ?item wdt:P19 / wdt:P131 / wdt:P131 wd:Q90 .
    } UNION {
        ?item wdt:P19 / wdt:P131 / wdt:P131 / wdt:P131 wd:Q90 .
    } UNION {
        ?item wdt:P19 / wdt:P131 / wdt:P131 / wdt:P131 / wdt:P131 wd:Q90 .
    }
    OPTIONAL {
        ?item wdt:P569 ?birth
    }
    FILTER(?birth > "1900-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)
    SERVICE wikibase:label
    {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    }
}
```

A couple of other comments:

- If you only want the count of people, you can replace the SELECT variables with a count, which may improve the runtime a bit: `SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count) WHERE { … }` which returns the answer 1440.
- The use of `OPTIONAL` to bind the `?birth` variable combined with the `FILTER` *outside of the `OPTIONAL`* may not be what you want. The Filter will remove any results where `?birth` is unbound, making the OPTIONAL really non-optional. Consider either removing the `OPTIONAL` and binding `?birth` right next to the `FILTER`, or moving the `FILTER` inside the `OPTIONAL` to apply that date range filter only to people who *have* birth data (which changes the count from 1440 to 2456 – many musicians born in Paris missing birth dates, it seems!)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the penalty is much smaller for the ? operator, so you can combine at least two of those queries with wdt:P19/wdt:P131?. Beyond that, I vaguely recall being more successful with wdt:P19/(wdt:P131|(wdt:P131/wdt:P131))? than the equivalent wdt:P19/wdt:P131{0,2}.